Webhook for Runa Playground API
I am migrating from connect Runa API to Runa API.
To test its implementation on playground I want to add a webhook with Runa playground API so that after processing the order the user should be notified in both success and failure. But I am unable to do this. How can I add Webhook for Runa playground API?
I am trying this method to create an order and it is working fine. order is placed on runa playground. And email is sent when order is placed.
but I want to attach a webhook to this which will notify me in case of "completed" or "failed"
using RestSharp;

var options = new RestClientOptions("https://playground.runa.io/v2/order");
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest("");
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("X-Idempotency-Key", "sssa111");
request.AddHeader("X-Send-Email", "true");
request.AddHeader("X-Execution-Mode", "async");
request.AddHeader("X-Api-Key", "XXEP3kp8.O(NOOeYie746e3%U3X_=UYuJ_hZGU&v6");
request.AddJsonBody("{\"payment_method\":     {\"type\":\"ACCOUNT_BALANCE\",\"currency\":\"GBP\"},\"items\":[{\"distribution_method\":{\"type\":\"EMAIL\",\"email_address\":\"abc@email.com\"},\"products\":{\"type\":\"SINGLE\",\"value\":\"abcd\"},\"face_value\":10}]}", false);
var response = await client.PostAsync(request);

